# JavaScript анимация перемещение элемента

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, анимация

У меня возникли проблемы с написанием одного на первый взгляд простенького кода. Я хотел создать небольшую анимацию, в ходе которой текстовый элемент html должен был перемещаться по экрану веб-страницы и менять направления после столкновения с краями. Проблема заключается в том, цикл, в котором происходит изменение параметров Margin элемента не обновляет отображение элемента на странице. Т.е. если сделать цикл конечным, элемент мгновенно переместится на свою конечную позицию, если же цикл бесконечный то страница просто будет грузиться вечно.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        'use strict';
        window.onload = function() {
            let movingElement = document.getElementById("movingThing");
            let destiny = [1, -1];
            let xDirection = destiny[Math.round(Math.random() * 1)];
            let yDirection = destiny[Math.round(Math.random() * 1)];
            let speed = 1;
            movingElement.style.marginTop = 200 + 'px';
            movingElement.style.marginLeft = 200 + 'px';
            for (let i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
                if (movingElement.style.marginTop >= document.body.clientHeight ||
                    movingElement.style.marginTop <= 0)
                    yDirection *= -1;
                if (movingElement.style.marginLeft >= document.body.clientWidth ||
                    movingElement.style.marginLeft <= 0)
                    xDirection *= -1;
                movingElement.style.marginTop = parseInt(movingElement.style.marginTop) + speed * yDirection + 'px'
                movingElement.style.marginLeft = parseInt(movingElement.style.marginLeft) + speed * xDirection + 'px'
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p style="font-size: 45px" id="movingThing">$</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

использовать вместо цикла `setInterval`

```js
let movingElement = document.getElementById("movingThing");

const windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
const elemWidth = movingElement.clientWidth;
const elemHeight = movingElement.clientHeight;

let destiny = [1, -1];
let xDirection = destiny[Math.round(Math.random() * 1)];
let yDirection = destiny[Math.round(Math.random() * 1)];
let speed = 1;

movingElement.style.top = 100 + 'px';
movingElement.style.left = 100 + 'px';

setInterval(() => {
  const top = parseInt(movingElement.style.top);
  const left = parseInt(movingElement.style.left);
  if (top == (windowHeight - elemHeight) || top == 0) yDirection *= -1;
  if (left == (windowWidth - elemWidth) || left == 0) xDirection *= -1;
  movingElement.style.top = top + speed * yDirection + 'px'
  movingElement.style.left = left + speed * xDirection + 'px'
}, 10)
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-size: 45px" id="movingThing">$</p>
```